# SharedMemory between user app and services

Tags: memory, shared

the code below was developed for shared memory. when it is used on two services or two user app, it work pretty well. but when the memory is created in service, the application can not find the memory. what is wrong with this code?

in service:

```
    mmf=MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("ALFMap",10000);
    bool mutexCreated;
    Mutex mutex=new Mutex(true,"ALFMutex",out mutexCreated);
    stream=mmf.CreateViewStream(0,1000);
    BinaryWriter writer=new BinaryWriter(stream);
    writer.Write("I am reza dadkhah");
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

in user app:

```
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("ALFMap",MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl))
            {
            Mutex mutex=Mutex.OpenExisting("ALFMutex");
            mutex.WaitOne();
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream=mmf.CreateViewStream(0,1000))
                {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                textBox1.Text=reader.ReadString();
                }
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the content of the memory in a file using your application ? Try that first and confirm the value is in the memory or not.